# Pyttsx3 nsss.py gives an weird @obj not defined error

Tags: python, module, runtime-error, pyttsx3

So I was using pyttsxx3 to do some tasks in python. It was working all fine till now, When I try to run it now it gives me error that in nsss.py obj not defined and tells if i meant @object.
Here is all the error msg I get:

I tried using pyttsx4 instead of pyttsx3.
Tried deleting nsss.py and reinstalling it.
Tried using different driver name in "init()".
While trying diff drivers, it didnt give me any error neither it ran.
I tried different solutions from stack overflow but nothing worked so far

````
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyttsx3/__init__.py", line 20, in init
    eng = _activeEngines[driverName]
          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/weakref.py", line 136, in __getitem__
    o = self.data[key]()
        ~~~~~~~~~^^^^^
KeyError: None

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/macbook_pro_7211/Project/webhelper/test2.py", line 3, in <module>
    h = pyttsx3.init()
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyttsx3/__init__.py", line 22, in init
    eng = Engine(driverName, debug)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyttsx3/engine.py", line 30, in __init__
    self.proxy = driver.DriverProxy(weakref.proxy(self), driverName, debug)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyttsx3/driver.py", line 50, in __init__
    self._module = importlib.import_module(name)
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1204, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1176, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1147, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 690, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 940, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyttsx3/drivers/nsss.py", line 12, in <module>
    class NSSpeechDriver(NSObject):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyttsx3/drivers/nsss.py", line 13, in NSSpeechDriver
    @objc.python_method
     ^^^^
NameError: name 'objc' is not defined. Did you mean: 'object'?```
````

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

try this one...

#Initialize the text-to-speech engine`engine = pyttsx3.init('dummy')`

Comment: Already Tried 
The execution just immediately stops when i run the program without speaking anything.

Answer (score 1):

I have removed pyttsx3 as there were multiple issues that open PR would resolve, but it is not merged currently.
After I installed pyttsx4, I added this line on nsss.py file

import objc

That fixes it!